# android app chrashed when replace strings

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception

I'm building an android app, that loads a json formatted text over the internet and show it on a simple list.
It works all fine, but when I replace a string, no matter what kind, my app crashes. Can you help me?

Here is the code:

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            holder.ivMovieIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            holder.tvMovie = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMovie);
            holder.tvTagline = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTagline);
            holder.tvYear = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvYear);
            holder.tvDuration = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);
            holder.tvDirector = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDirector);
            holder.rbMovieRating = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbMovie);
            holder.tvCast = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCast);
            holder.tvStory = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvStory);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        // Then later, when you want to display image
        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(movieModelList.get(position).getImage(), holder.ivMovieIcon, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                finalHolder.ivMovieIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finalHolder.ivMovieIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finalHolder.ivMovieIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finalHolder.ivMovieIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        holder.tvMovie.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getMovie());
        holder.tvTagline.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getTagline());
        holder.tvYear.setText("Year: " + movieModelList.get(position).getYear());
        holder.tvDuration.setText("Duration:" + movieModelList.get(position).getDuration());
        holder.tvDirector.setText("Director:" + movieModelList.get(position).getDirector());

        // rating bar
        holder.rbMovieRating.setRating(movieModelList.get(position).getRating()/2);

        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(MovieModel.Cast cast : movieModelList.get(position).getCastList()){
            stringBuffer.append(cast.getName() + ", ");
        }

        holder.tvCast.setText("Cast:" + stringBuffer);
        holder.tvStory.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getStory());
        return convertView;
    }
```

The get-method of getDirector is:

```
public String getDirector() {
    return director;
}

public void setDirector(String director) {
    this.director = director;
}
```

When I change this line:

```
holder.tvDirector.setText("Director:" + movieModelList.get(position).getDirector());
```

to

```
holder.tvDirector.setText("Director:" + movieModelList.get(position).getDirector().replace("test","test1"));
```

my App crashed. But why ? How can I replace this text for example ?

Thanks for your help

That is the Logcat:

```
07-22 14:33:23.233 2714-2714/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at com.hisham.jsonparsingdemo.MainActivity$MovieAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:219)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1622)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2106)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:493)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1868)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1689)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Cause of the error is `NPE` (Null Pointer Exception).

It looks like you have null data from array list.

The line above will not crash if `getDirector()` returns null

```
holder.tvDirector.setText("Director:" + movieModelList.get(position).getDirector());
```

But when you add `replace("test","test1") part, if the movieModelList.get(position).getDirector() is null, it will crash.

You need to add extra Null check or use TextUtils.isEmpty() method like below:

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(movieModelList.get(position).getDirector())){
    holder.tvDirector.setText("Director:" + movieModelList.get(position).getDirector().replace("test","test1"));
}else{
    holder.tvDirector.setText("Director:" + "write something else");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all there should always be a null check, if we are fetching values from API
in your case it should be like this :

```
if(null != movieModelList && null != movieModelList.get(position) && null != movieModelList.get(position).getDirector()){
  //here you can set text or do things this will help you avoid unnecessary crashes of data not available/null pointer from API
}
```

Also kindly use braces to make code easily readable. 
It will help other person to maintain the code.

```
holder.tvDirector.setText("Director:" + (movieModelList.get(position).getDirector()).replace("test","test1"));
```

Last but not the least
provide us your logs so that we can help u better
:)